# How should I repair flaking paint?

Tags: repair, painting

I have just removed some frog tape from a painted wall and it has taken the paint off down to the plasterboard (4 layers, 2 undercoat and 2 topcoat).

How should I go about repairing the damaged areas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you have quite a divot that needs some filling.  I recommend using lightweight Spackle. It is very easy to apply, and you can smooth it with fine sandpaper and a damp sponge about 15 mins after you apply it and paint it within an hour.

Comment: I ended up using some crack filler I already had, along with using a damp sponge to blend it in. It looks pretty good to my eye (untrained). I'll paint it later tonight and see how it holds up. It will be partially covered by some flock material, so should be fine in terms of longevity. Anyway, thanks for the answer and +1 for the damp sponge suggestion.